# jQuery Do not append on table if the specific value already exist

Tags: jquery

My Code is totally all working fine but my only concern is how can I validate if the appended value already exist on the table. This is what i've done.

```
<body>
<form>
    <select id="name">
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
        <option value="James">James</option>
        <option value="Steve">Steve</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
<table id="dynamic_field"></table>
```

My concern is only on the  `if ($('#dynamic_field').has(name))`  part. I want to validate if it already exist.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;  
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        i++;
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var markup = '<tr id="row'+i+'"> <td> <button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove">Delete </button> </td> <td> <input type="text" value="'+name+'" name="owners"> '+name+'</td> </tr>';
        if(name != '-') {
            if ($('#dynamic_field').has(name)) {
                alert('already exists in the table');
            } else {
                $('#dynamic_field').append(markup);
            }
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
     var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
     $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
 });  
});
```

Comment: you can try using  
 $('#dynamic_field').find(":input[value= " + name+ "]").length

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use selector to fetch a value exist in a table.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;  
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        i++;
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var markup = '<tr id="row'+i+'"> <td> <button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove">Delete </button> </td> <td> <input type="text" value="'+name+'" name="owners"> '+name+'</td> </tr>';
        if(name != '-') {
            var isExists=false;
            $("#dynamic_field tr input").each(function(){
              var val=$(this).val();
              if(val==name)
                isExists=true;
            }).val()
            if (isExists) {
                alert('already exists in the table');
            } else {
                $('#dynamic_field').append(markup);
            }
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
     var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
     $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
 });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="name">
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
        <option value="James">James</option>
        <option value="Steve">Steve</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
<table id="dynamic_field"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

.has() returns jquery element, so you have to check the length and since name is variable not any selector, so you have to associate value attribute in it.

```
if( $('#dynamic_field').has(":input[value="+name+"]").length ) {
   alert('already exists in the table');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a bit of vanilla JS, you could take advantage of the (relatively new) `querySelectorAll` method which takes a selector string similar to jQuery's, and is a bit faster since, well, it's plain JS.

Since you are naming the inputs, you might as well use their name attribute to select them:

- `'#dynamic_field input[name=owners]'` selects the inputs
- `document.querySelectorAll('#dynamic_field input[name=owners]')` returns a NodeList
- `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#dynamic_field input[name=owners]'))` converts said NodeList into an array so we can use `some()` on it
- `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#dynamic_field input[name=owners]')).some(input => input.value === name);` returns true if there is at least one element that satisfies the condition `input.value === name`.

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

[some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;  
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var markup = '<tr id="row'+i+'"> <td> <button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove">Delete </button> </td> <td> <input type="text" value="'+name+'" name="owners"> '+name+'</td> </tr>';
    
        if(name !== '-'){
          const exists = Array.from(
                             document.querySelectorAll(
                                 '#dynamic_field input[name=owners]'
                             )).some(input => input.value === name);
          
          if (exists) {
              alert('already exists in the table');
          } else {
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_field').append(markup);
          }
        }     
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
     var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
     $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
 });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="name">
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
        <option value="James">James</option>
        <option value="Steve">Steve</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
<table id="dynamic_field"></table>
```